# Searching for strings commonly found in code using Google

Tags: grails, search-engine, search

Questions:

**How do you search for non-alphanumeric characters when using Google?**

**Why doesn't Google always interpret strings enclosed within double-quotes literally?**

**What is Google's escape character e.g. how would I search for something that contains a double-quote?**

---

Backgound:

I am currently learning Grails. I was reading [Mastering Grails: Grails services and Google Maps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails05208/index.html) (which is very good tutorial series BTW) when I came across the following line of code:

```
def result = [:]
```

By looking at the surrounding code it seems like `result` is defined to be some kind of map, but I wanted more information on what precisely "`=[:]`" does.

**How do you Google something like this?**

I tried searching for:

```
grails "[:]"
```

but this returns the same result set as searching for "`grails`".

That happens because searching just for:

```
"[:]"
```

does not return any results.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[:] is an empty map in Groovy

You can [learn more about maps and collections here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections) or [focus on Groovy maps](http://blog.adaptivesoftware.biz/2009/04/groovy-maps.html).

I think you are assuming that Google is going to do a simple 'grep' where their infrastructure is more setup to search based on a linguistic model.

You might try [Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch)

I would encourage you to pull up the [Groovy Console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) (`groovyConsole` on the command-line if you have groovy setup) and play around with maps and lists to get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks @lael for pointing me to the documentation! My questions about using google remain though :( Are you saying google does not index the non-alphanumeric characters at all? I always thought search strings enclosed within double-quotes are searched for "as-is" (i.e. not applying any linguistic logic)?

Comment: See http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=134479

It says that: "punctuation is ignored (that is, you can't search for @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters)."

Google's Search is very linguistic in nature, and therefore doesn't work that well for code.  When using Google you are searching for 'words' and not binary patterns that a grep or a regular expression would be used for.  I think that is one reason that they started Google Codesearch.  http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en

Comment: Aha, I see. Thant would explain it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: +1 for Code Search. I believe it lets you use regular expressions to search.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot search non-alphanumeric characters in Google. Google strips the symbols, treating them as whitespace.

For that, you have to turn to a search engine like SymbolHound, that is specifically designed for programmers. It primarily indexes StackOverflow, and the index of other programming sites (forums, questions and answer sites, etc.) is growing.

http://www.symbolhound.com

-Tom [full disclosure: I am a co-founder of SymbolHound]

Comment: I like the concept of your search engine although I have to say I find the search results page hard to read and an eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

For code-related searches that Google has a tendency to stumble over I usually try [duckduckgo](http://www.duckduckgo.com). For example, it at least brings up something for [[:]](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5B%3A%5D), even if it isn't always what you're looking for.